# Why is ctx.drawImage only drawing part of the video element to canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I am trying to draw a movie frame to the canvas element using `ctx.DrawImage` and I am getting what I think are very weird scaling / cropping behaviors.

First, here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <video autoplay width="125" height="125"></video>
    <img src="">
    <canvas></canvas>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var localMediaStream = null;

    function snapshot() {
        if (localMediaStream) {
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 125, 125);
            document.querySelector('img').src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
        }
    }   

video.addEventListener('click', snapshot, false);

navigator.getUserMedia(

    {
        video: true

    }, function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        localMediaStream = stream;
});
```

What this does is essentially take the still from the video and squish it so that it is about 1/3 the original width and about 70% of the height. This is frustrating.

Leaving off the `125` and just using  `ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0)` fills the canvas with the still, however, it is only about the top left corner (25%) of the image.  This is also frustrating.

How can I make the canvas draw the exact same sized image as the video element is playing?

This is coupled with the fact  the video element itself is indeed `125px x 125px` but my because of the aspect ratio, there is letter boxing (white space) around the video element.  Is there a way to force the video element to fill itself with the incoming video stream?

Comment: try to set your canvas `height`/`width` to `video.videoHeight`/`video.videoWidth` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a webcam (with the `navigator.getUserMedia` function).  The webcam resolution was significantly higher and so, even when the sizes of the video element and canvas were the same, the image being captured was much larger than could fit.

The solution was to add a `constrain` property to make the media stream also `125px x 125px`

Comment: be aware that constrains only work for chrome right now

Comment: Hi! How do you add these constraints? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I too was facing the same problem when I tried...

```
var sw = video.offsetWidth, // source width
    sh = video.offsetHeight, // source height
    dw = canvas.width, // destination width
    dh = canvas.height; // destination height
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, sw, sh, 0, 0, dw, dh);
```

it got solved when I changed to :

```
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, dw, dh);
```

I believe in your case the problem is, `125` is height and width of video element, but what you should be supplying is the canvas height and width, for example, setting the canvas width and height:

```
canvas.width = 125;
canvas.height = 125;
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 125, 125);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very old question, but I was faced with a similar challenge a few days back.

Making use of CSS viewport units  to set height & width of the canvas and also adjust size of the  tags saved my day.

Viewport units allow you to size elements and font sizes as a percentage of the total width or height of the user’s screen (the viewport).

This is how i implemented in my code

The video tags

```
<video id="video" style="height: calc(25vh - 15px); width: calc(25vh - 15px); border: 1px solid gray;" autoplay playsinline></video>
```

You can read more about them here https://alligator.io/css/viewport-units/